# dynamic Jquery ui photo manager with multiple draggable and droppable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

i am new to jquery . i just saw the photo manager example in http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager jquery ui website . i wanted to make those elements in the gallery droppable in multiple multiple div and get dynamic elements from database for eg we take 4 photos from database then i wanted to make those four photos draggable and droppable to multiple div's such as photo 1 , 2 , 3 are draggable and droppable to div 1 and div 2 and so on . and when we drop the photo in any one of the div the position of photo gets saved on that div itself so that even when we refresh the page the photo stays in that div which we had dropped it . can anyone help me out with this please.

Comment: you have to save the data to the server, which means you can use php, and mysql, or used cookies, if you don't want to remember for a long time, using ajax will allow you to update the order its a little more complicated, I think you are trying to run, before you can walk :)

Comment: the database part is one which i can handle but i need to create multiple div . which in the above example is only one which is the trash . i want multiple trash divs draggable and droppable with elements .

Comment: Thats, just easy, add a class to your trash div, then change the accept to what ever the class is so it would look like `... accept: '.my_drop_class',....` if that makes sense. http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept read more about accept option should be easy